# How to translate shutter speed values into usable data?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm gathering light statistics of EXIF data for a large collection of photos and I'm trying to find the simplest way (i.e. performance doesn't matter) of translating Exposure Time values to/from *usable data*. There is (as far as I can find) no standard for what values camera manufacturers might use i.e. I can't just scan the web for random images and hard-code a map.

Here are is a sample set of values I've encountered (**"** indicates seconds):

> 279", 30", 5", 3.2", 1.6", 1.3", 1", 1/1.3, 1/1.6, 1/2, 1/2.5, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/8, 1/13, 1/8000, 1/16000

Also take into consideration that I'd also like to find the average (mean) ... but it should be one of the *actual* shutter speeds collected and not just some arbitrary number.

EDIT:
By *usable data* I mean some sort of creative? numbering system that I can convert to/from for performing calculations. I thought about just multiplying everything by 1,000,000 except some fractions when divided are quite exotic.

EDIT #2:
To clarify, I'm using ExposureTime instead of ShutterSpeed because it contains *photographer friendly* values e.g. 1/50. ShutterSpeed is more of an approximation (which varies between camera manufacturers) and leads to values such as 1/49.

Comment: what do you mean by usable data?

Comment: Are you saying that you get the shutter speeds as strings, like "1/1.6"? How are you getting these values?

Comment: @Gabe he's getting them through EXIF metadata, so they are strings, yes.

Comment: Sheeo: EXIF data stores the shutter speed in two different ways, but both are as rational numbers. See http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF and search for `ExposureTime` and `ShutterSpeed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to parse them into some kind of time-duration object.

A simple way, looking at that data, would be to check wheter " or / occurs, if " parse as seconds, / parse as fraction of seconds. I don't really understand what else you could mean. For an example you'd need to specify a language--also, there might be a parser out there already.

Comment: Language is C# / NET 3.5 (as listed in the keywords). I am parsing as you suggest however the fractions are nasty to convert to/from e.g. 1/1.3 or 1/3.

Comment: Store them in lookup tables like Hash tables or a Dictionary.  Use the tables to translate between the string (for user display or for EXIF interchange) and the double for any math computations.

Comment: @Les,Sheeo Your answers combined are the obvious and/or IMO "normal" answer. In retrospect, I guess my mind was secretly focused on finding some clever new NET 3.x language feature. Silly me, stick to what works or at least specify my intent better in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Shutter speed is encoded in the EXIF metadata as an SRATIONAL, 32-bits for the numerator and 32-bits for the denominator.  Sample code that retrieves it, using System.Drawing:

```
        var bmp = new Bitmap(@"c:\temp\canon-ixus.jpg");
        if (bmp.PropertyIdList.Contains(37377)) {
            byte[] spencoded = bmp.GetPropertyItem(37377).Value;
            int numerator = BitConverter.ToInt32(spencoded, 0);
            int denominator = BitConverter.ToInt32(spencoded, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("Shutter speed = {0}/{1}", numerator, denominator);
        }
```

Output: Shutter speed = 553859/65536, sample image [retrieved here](http://www.exif.org/samples.html).

Comment: I'm using EXPOSURETIME in lieu, as ShutterSpeed gives values that are a bit _too_ accurate. I prefer the familiar 1/50 instead of the _actual_ value of 1/49.

Comment: Okay, whatever you like.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sadly not. I already have the EXIF data parsed I just wanted some cleverly simple way of working with it.

Comment: You're too clever for me, I have no idea what you're talking about.  Not putting these details in your question was a bad idea.

Comment: I edited the question with the details, but I agree. Asking questions can be more difficult than finding an answer.

Comment: glenneroo: The ShutterSpeed is also stored as SRATIONAL, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are three types of string you will encounter:

1. String with double quotes `"` for seconds
2. String with leading `1/`
3. String with no special characters

I propose you simply test for these conditions and parse the value accordingly using floats:

```
    string[] InputSpeeds = new[] { "279\"", "30\"", "5\"", "3.2\"", "1.6\"", "1.3\"", "1\"", "1/1.3", "1/1.6", "1/2", "1/2.5", "1/3", "1/4", "1/5", "1/8", "1/13", "1/8000", "1/16000" };
    List<float> OutputSpeeds = new List<float>();

    foreach (string s in InputSpeeds)
    {
        float ConvertedSpeed;
        if (s.Contains("\""))
        {
            float.TryParse(s.Replace("\"", String.Empty), out ConvertedSpeed);
            OutputSpeeds.Add(ConvertedSpeed);
        }
        else if (s.Contains("1/"))
        {
            float.TryParse(s.Remove(0, 2), out ConvertedSpeed);
            if (ConvertedSpeed == 0)
            {
                OutputSpeeds.Add(0F);
            }
            else
            {
                OutputSpeeds.Add(1 / ConvertedSpeed);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            float.TryParse(s, out ConvertedSpeed);
            OutputSpeeds.Add(ConvertedSpeed);
        }
    }
```

If you want `TimeSpan`s simply change the `List<float>` to `List<TimeSpan>` and instead of adding the float to the list, use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ConvertedSpeed);`

Comment: ooh thanks, I totally forgot about TimeSpan! And the parser works great too! :)